# Return individual words that matched search result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

While doing a search with Elasticsearch I can use the [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) to see which individual words were used to return the search, but how can get a list of these words?

Example: If I do a search for `a*e`, I might get a result that has both `ale` and `apple`, and this will be shown in the highlights as `...some text <strong>ale</strong>; some text <strong>apple</strong>`

How can I get just the words that matched the search? e.g., `["ale", "apple"]`

Comment: You can't. Elasticsearch gives you back documents, not terms or words. This is how it works. Highlighting is the closest feature you can use for something like this.